# What's the geometric meaning of total positivity?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, determinant, matrix-calculus

Is there a geometric meaning of total positivity? I wanted to thought of it as a measure of volume but there wasn't a derivative definition associated with the total positivity. But does it define some sort of the parity like the orientation?

See the definition of [total positivity](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Total_positivity)

Comment: I haven't worked through it in detail but the wikipedia page on total positivity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_positive_matrix suggests that it's linked to compound matrices https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_matrix; I'd expect that you get a compound matrix of your totally positive matrix by putting the determinants from the definition of total positivity into a matrix. This then suggests that it represents an exterior power of the linear map induced by the original matrix which brings you towards a geometric interpretation.